# Организация таблиц бд

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сайт, на котором будут размещаться статьи. Я создал таблицу в базе, в которой собираюсь хранить привью статьи, она содержит такие поля:

1. id
2. article_id - id статьи из таблицы articles
3. article_type - тип статьи(всего 3 типа)
4. date - дата публикации  descript - краткое содержание статьи
5. header - заголовок
6. views_count - количество просмотров

И ещё одну таблицу в которой будет сам текст статьи. Её структура:

1. id
2. content - содержимое статьи (3-5 тыс. символов)

Логика работы такая, когда пользователь открывает страницу со списком, то из базы выгибаются все записи первой таблицы. Когда он щелкает на какую-то конкретно статью, то из второй таблицы вытягивается контент, а из первой поля `header` и `views_count`, т.е. дергаются две таблицы.

Думаю может объединить их  в одну и на странице списка вытягивать все поля, но не трогать поле `content`, а на странице статьи только вытягивать `header` и `views_count`? Как правильно?

Comment: Если у вас связь один к одному (а у вас как раз она), то разбивать на две таблицы особого смысла нет

Comment: @rjhdby, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что лучше объединить таблицы. Или Вам по т3 надо иметь именно две?

Comment: хорошо, спасибо) Да у меня то и тз нет, я для себя делаю, набираюсь опыта так сказать.